# About the braces in a 'case' statement in 'switch'

Tags: c++, switch-statement, case

Today, while I was trying to write code to just add and subtract the two 2*2 matrices, in which I used a *switch* statement, I got an error:

> case bypass initialization of local variable in function main()

#### Code

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main()
{
    int mat1[2][2], mat2[2][2], mat3[2][2];

    cout << "Enter the elements in the first matrix";
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            cin >> mat1[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\nEnter the elements of the second matrix";

    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
            cin >> mat2[k][l];
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\nsaved......";

    int choice;
    cout << "\n\n\nFor adding these two matrices,press 1";
    cout << "\nFor subtracting these two matrices,press 2";
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:

        cout << "The addition of the two matrices will yield";
        for (int a = 0; a <= 1; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b <= 1; b++) {
                mat3[a][b] = mat1[a][b] + mat2[a][b];
            }
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        cout << "The subtraction of the two matrices will yield";
        for (int c = 0; c <= 1; c++) {
            for (int d = 0; d <= 1; d++) {
                mat3[c][d] = mat1[c][d] - mat2[c][d];
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I also found that I can take the rid of this error by placing the code of case(s), into braces, NOW,

1. my confusion is about the `error`...
2. & the requirement of braces in `case`....

(I know I haven't used the new coding conventions, like `<iostream>`, std namespace, etc., etc. as I have written it in the [Turbo C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B) compiler, so a to-the-point answer is humbly requested.)

Comment: Which line of code is generating that error?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but both branches of the case statement add the two matrices, and nothing prints them back out afterward.  I'm guessing that's not what you meant.

Comment: The bold text doesn't tell us what line it refers to; see my answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A switch statement is just a bunch of labels and a `goto` done by the compiler depending on the value of the thing inside the `switch` test.

When you have a local variable in a function, anywhere past the declaration of that variable you can use it. For instance:

```
int a;
// can use a now
```

However, in a `switch` statement, if you have a local variable:

```
case a:
    int a;
    break;
case b:
    // we can use a here because these cases are just labels used in a goto
    // i.e. the cases do *not* create a new scope
```

So when you have a variable in a `case`, the variable exists in `case`s below it but the variable won't exist because the code that initialized it got skipped by the case statement. It's hard for me to explain, maybe someone else can do a better job.

The braces fix this problem because they make the variable local, so that it doesn't exist in subsequent `case`s. It only gets created if that particular `case` gets entered, and if you forget a `break` and control falls through to the next `case`, the ending `}` ends the scope and causes the variable to be destroyed so it's not accessible from the next `case`, and the initialization can't be skipped.

So just remember that all the `case`s share scope. That might help you understand this.

Comment: I don't see a similar situation in the code OP posted. Infact it compiles happily on gcc, http://www.ideone.com/tgpuT

Comment: @Als yes I know, because the scope of the variables in the `for` loop is controlled, but I don't know how he could get that error message without that situation, so I assumed that code isn't the source of the error, or it isn't real.

Comment: Because he is using a crappy old compiler which does not conform to the standards.

Comment: @Als: To be fair, it probably conformed to the de facto standard that existed at the time.  I think Stroustrup mentions this issue in "The Design and Evolution of C++".

Answer (score 7):

After re-indenting your code and changing a few things so it compiles on my system, g++ compiles it without warnings.

My best guess is that it has something to do with the old rules for the scope of an object declared in a for loop (it used to live until the end of the enclosing scope; in modern C++ it's limited to the loop itself), but I can't quite be sure.

To help us figure this out, please indent the code properly, and show us the exact error message, including the line number.  If the error says "line 42: ...", add a comment in your source like  `// this is line 42`.

EDIT: Yes, I think that's the problem.  In modern C++, your code is ok, because the loop variables are scoped to the loops themselves.  Apparently Turbo implements a very old version of the language, so your variable `a`, for example, is visible all the way to the bottom of the `switch` statement.  Enclosing each `for` loop in curly braces should avoid the warning:

```
{
    for (int a = 0; a <= 1; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b <= 1; b++) {
            mat3[a][b] = mat1[a][b] + mat2[a][b];
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT2: Or better yet, stop using Turbo C++ and get a modern compiler.

EDIT3: And the reason that compiler warns about this is that even though it appears that `i` is always initialized before use, you could in principle refer to `i` in the `case 2:` section, bypassing the initialization.  (Again, this only applies under the old rules.)

A cleaner way to work around this is probably to enclose each `case` section in braces:

```
switch (choice) {
    case 1: {
        ...
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        ...
        break;
    }
}
```

(or, again, get a modern compiler, unless you have a really good reason to stick with Turbo C++).

Comment: respected sir,actually there is no way to do so in  turbo c++,..& the error message is same as is shown by me in the bold text,in the question

Comment: Really?  It just gives you an error message without telling you what line in the source it's complaining about?  Or does it dump you into an editor with the cursor on the offending line?  If so, which line is it?

Comment: it highlights the text "case 1:" only

Comment: My +1, This is the correct answer. Please link to [this](http://www.ideone.com/tgpuT), which shows it will work with Standard compliant compiler like gcc.

Comment: Ah yes, it could be the old `for` scoping. Wow, that's old.

Comment: There's an old macro trick for this problem. Strictly illegal but it works `#define for if (0) ; else for`. Put that at the start of your code and every for loop gets put into an else block and so the proper scoping rules apply. Saved me days of work once and I've remembered it ever since.

Comment: Turbo C++ (from the 1990s) is *required* by many Indian engineering schools (or *required* at the *mandatory* internship place for the students). This is *still* the case in 2020, as documented in several [videos by Joshua Fluke](https://www.youtube.com/c/JoshuaFluke1/videos) (I can't find an exact reference, but it is within the last year or so).

Answer (score 5):

A `case` block is not a new scope by itself. Any variable you declare within one is visible for the rest of the `switch` statement. But in the other `case` blocks, it's uninitialized. By adding the braces, you create a new scope so the other blocks can't see it.

For example:

```
switch (choice)
{
case 0:
    int a = 42;
    break;


case 1:
    std::cout << a << std::endl; // 'a' is uninitialized here
    break;
}


switch (choice)
{
case 0:
    {
        int a = 42;
        break;
    }


case 1:
    std::cout << a << std::endl; // error -- 'a' is not declared here
    break;
}
```

I don't see a situation like this in the code you posted, but that's what the error message means.

Comment: You might want to link to (this) [http://www.ideone.com/tgpuT] gcc-4.3.4 shows no error.

Comment: @Als: Did you try it with -Wall?

Comment: @Als: You mean [here](http://www.ideone.com/tgpuT). That's the OP's code? As I said, I don't see this situation in that code. I don't think we're seeing the code with the problem or with the braces that fix it.