# switch statement C++ with some commands

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have a question.
How more correct use operator switch with blocks of commands:

```
switch(a)
{
   case 1: 
        {
         command1;
         command2;
         commandN;
         break;
        }
   case 2: 
        {
         command3;
         command4;
         commandN;
         break;
        }
}
```

or

```
switch(a)
{
   case 1: 
         command1;
         command2;
         commandN;
         break;

   case 2:       
         command3;
         command4;
         commandN;
         break;     
}
```

Use or not { ... } in case? Any version is working, but how more correctly?
Thanks.

Comment: `command<x>;` actually looks like a NOP?

Comment: You only need the braces if you're going to use local variables within the case block.

Comment: Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241545/c-switch-case-curly-braces-after-every-case

Comment: Upvoted because this is a valid question; I've often thought about it.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews C'mon, it's pretty obvious when you'll need braces or not.

Comment: Actually, my question is whether the `break` should be inside the braces or not.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044574/about-the-braces-in-case-statement-in-switch

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It doesn't matter, but I personally prefer to keep it outside.

Comment: _@Влад Март_ _"Any version is working ..."_ Not really, it depends what you need to have inside the `case` section. Your (pseudoi) code sample is meaningless.

Comment: Compare [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/818cba8dde9517bc) vs [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a409eafbd3e4bcb5)